# how to debug javax.net.ssl package

Tags: java, ssl, logback

I use a robust java [server](https://github.com/nordic-institute/X-Road).
For some unknown reason I receiving a

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Invalid ECDH ServerKeyExchange signature
exception
```

As one of the way how to solve this issue I want to debug javax.net.ssl package.

I set the following logback settings:
`<logger name="javax.net.ssl" level="TRACE" />`

Unfortunately, I haven't got any new details.
Could someone please share other ways how to fix it or receiving more information?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html

Answer (score 0):

The `curl -vs https://example.com` command helps me to understand that I have a SSL certificate problem: `unable to get local issuer certificate`.